# Composable does not render with LocalContext.current as Activity

Tags: android

I read [Jetpack Compose Preview Render Problem when casting LocalContext.current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345509/jetpack-compose-preview-render-problem-when-casting-localcontext-current) and I am wondering if there's a way to fix this without implementing an interface.

I'm following https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-sports-app?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-sports-app#1

Code here: https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-sports/tree/starter

My changes:

```
diff --git a/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt b/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt
index 7a24a19..e9d96f4 100644
--- a/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt
+++ b/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt
@@ -16,6 +16,7 @@
 
 package com.example.sports.ui
 
+import android.app.Activity
 import androidx.activity.compose.BackHandler
 import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
 import androidx.compose.foundation.background
@@ -48,6 +49,7 @@ import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
 import androidx.compose.material3.Text
 import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
 import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
+import androidx.compose.material3.windowsizeclass.WindowWidthSizeClass
 import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
 import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
 import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
@@ -56,6 +58,7 @@ import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
 import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
 import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
 import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
+import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
 import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLayoutDirection
 import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
 import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
@@ -76,6 +79,8 @@ import com.example.sports.ui.theme.SportsTheme
  */
 @Composable
 fun SportsApp(
+    windowSize: WindowWidthSizeClass,
+    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
 ) {
     val viewModel: SportsViewModel = viewModel()
     val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
@@ -342,6 +347,48 @@ private fun SportsDetail(
     }
 }
 
+@Composable
+fun SportsListAndDetails(
+    uiState: SportsUiState,
+    viewModel: SportsViewModel,
+    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
+) {
+    val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
+
+    Scaffold(
+        topBar = {
+            SportsAppBar(
+                isShowingListPage = true,
+                onBackButtonClick = { activity.finish() },
+            )
+        }
+    ) { innerPadding ->
+        Row(modifier = modifier) {
+            SportsList(
+                sports = uiState.sportsList,
+                onClick = {
+                    viewModel.updateCurrentSport(it)
+                    viewModel.navigateToDetailPage()
+                },
+                contentPadding = innerPadding,
+                modifier = Modifier
+                    .fillMaxWidth()
+                    .padding(
+                        top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                        start = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                        end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                    )
+            )
+            SportsDetail(
+                selectedSport = uiState.currentSport,
+                contentPadding = innerPadding,
+                onBackPressed = { activity.finish() },
+                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
+            )
+        }
+    }
+}
+
 @Preview
 @Composable
 fun SportsListItemPreview() {
@@ -365,3 +412,15 @@ fun SportsListPreview() {
         }
     }
 }
+
+@Preview
+@Composable
+fun SportsListAndDetailsPreview() {
+    SportsTheme {
+        Surface {
+            val viewModel: SportsViewModel = viewModel()
+            val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
+            SportsListAndDetails(uiState = uiState, viewModel = viewModel)
+        }
+    }
+}
```

though the preview won't render. If I remove/comment out `val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity` then the render works.

Any thoughts?

I don't want to look at the code solution in the codelab as I want to learn how to debug these issues if they occur again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previews are rendered on a desktop operating system: Linux, mac OS, or Windows.

Similar to unit tests, some Android-specific classes, like `Activity`, are not available in previews.

I suggest that you refactor your `SportsListAndDetails()` composable to take an `onFinish: () -> Unit = {}` lambda parameter, which you call in lieu of `activity.finish()`, and have `onFinish` call `finish()` someplace higher where you don't have a preview.